# How do I make a CSS grid cell collapse when empty or using display:none?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

**TL;DR**: Codepen https://codepen.io/veleek/pen/YmJGjY shows that grid cell with `display: none` seems to cause adjacent cell to take up less space instead of collapsing to nothing.

I'm creating a simple CSS Grid layout with a banner at the top with a logo, title, link bar, and a content block underneath.

[image: Rough layout]

For pages without nav links I'd like to collapse the nav section so that the title takes up the entire space.  Effectively I want that grid cell to be 0px tall.

Unfortunately, when I set `display: none` on that cell, it disappears but it seems to take up MORE space.  This actually causes the title to collapse itself down to be SMALLER then when that cell is present.

[image: Title collapsing to be smaller]

The image size is not fixed at 150px and I'd prefer to avoid fixed sizes if possible.  I just want to force that grid row to have 0 height when it's empty.  I've tried a bunch of combinations of `display:block/flex`, `align-items/justify-content/etc.: stretch/center/etc.` but nothing seems to work.

I've got a CodePen showing the issue here: https://codepen.io/veleek/pen/YmJGjY

Comment: I believe this issue is more thoroughly answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50708974/how-do-you-collapse-unused-row-in-a-css-grid

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is related to the definition of `auto` for a grid row.  According to [`grid-row-template` MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-rows#Values) `auto` is:

> Is a keyword that is identical to maximal content if it's a maximum. As a minimum it represents the largest minimum size (as specified by min-width/min-height) of the grid items occupying the grid track.

So when there is content in the track, it acts as a maximum and sizes correctly.  But when there is no content in the `clue-nav` element, it appears to fallback to the minimum definition, and since the only grid item occupying the track is the image in `clue-logo` so the minimum ends up getting set to a much larger value.  As everything resolves itself, the "empty" grid cell gets a bunch more space, and the `clue-title` grid cell ends up taking up the actual "minimum" amount of space that it needs.

To work around this issue, instead of setting the height to `auto`, you can use `minmax(0, auto)`.  This allows the actual minimum height of the row to go to zero instead of the `clue-logo` height, and it properly collapses when `clue-nav` is hidden.

I stumbled on this while fiddling around with Sølve's suggested answer, I noticed a bit more odd behavior around how it would decide to resize the row.  So kudos to him for helping me stumble onto the right answer.

Comment: Cool! Creative way to solve it with with minmax! Way over my head This answer makes me want to dive deeper in to css grid

Answer (score 1):

You can set:
grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;

Answer (score 0):

You can use `grid-row-start` and set it to start at the first row:

```
#clue-title1, #clue-title2 {
    grid-area: clue-title;
    grid-row-start: 1;
}
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px red solid;
} 

#clue-wrapper1, #clue-wrapper2 {
    display: grid;
    grid:
        "clue-logo clue-nav" auto
        "clue-logo clue-title" auto
        "clue-content clue-content" 1fr
        / auto 1fr;
}

#clue-logo1, #clue-logo2
{
    grid-area: clue-logo;
    
    display: flex;
    align-content: center;
}

#clue-nav1, #clue-nav2 {
    grid-area: clue-nav;
}

#clue-nav2 {
   display: none;
}

#clue-title1, #clue-title2 {
    grid-area: clue-title;
    grid-row-start: 1;
}

#clue-content1, #clue-content2 {
    grid-area: clue-content;
    min-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="clue-wrapper1">
  <div id="clue-logo1"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"/></div>
  <div id="clue-nav1">Sample navigation items</div>
  <div id="clue-title1"><h1>Title</h1></div>
  <div id="clue-content1">Content</div>
</div>

<hr/>

<div id="clue-wrapper2">
  <div id="clue-logo2"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"/></div>
  <div id="clue-nav2">Sample navigation items</div>
  <div id="clue-title2"><h1>Title</h1></div>
  <div id="clue-content2">Content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This seems to work for relatively simple scenarios, but it's a little bit more difficult for dynamic things where content may be added or removed from the `#clue-nav` section at runtime.  In order to handle that I would have to add and remove `grid-row-start: 1;` whenever that happens.  Additionally, if I change the grid layout to add another row above, I'll need to go through and modify all that.  I'd really like a solution that allows the grid cell to collapse down to zero height when empty.